# Moq c# Directory methods unit test

Tags: c#, moq

I would like to write unit tests for methods such as Directory.GetFiles() but it takes path as parameter. I have an interface that contains the method GetAllFiles which internally calls this method. I have mocked it up like follows:

```
var mockFile = new Mock<IFileImplement>();
mockFile.Setup(_ => _.GetAllFiles(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new[] {"text1.txt", "text2.txt"});
```

However, when I call the GetAllFiles method to test it, what path should be fed in? Since I do not want it to check in an actual directory, but I get error that the path could not be found?

Comment: Moq can't mock static methods in the first place. Either pass the path to a test folder, or wrap calls to `Directory` in eg a `FileSystemProvider` or something similar. ASP.NET Core uses [File Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to allow accessing assets stored either on disk (wwwroot, js, css) or embedded in assemblies. You'd have to modify your code to use the file provider instead of `Directory` or `File`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. GetAllFiles method implements the Directory method and takes in path as the parameter. So, I was mocking this method not the static method directly. But do you mean I should replace the Directory.GetFiles method with method in File Providers?

Comment: In that case you can use any string. You mocked your own instance method to return a specific result no matter what the input is. You can pass any value you want, including an empty string, eg `mockFile.GetAllFiles("");`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. If I pass an empty string, I get message: The path is empty. And if I pass some dummy value, it complains that the directory is not there. I do not want my unit tests to actually look into the directories, hence why I'm mocking. Please advise.

Comment: I can't offer any advice without the *actual* code. If the interface is eg `IDirectory`, the mock should be `var mock=new Mock<IDirectory>();`, not `new Mock();`. The errors you mentioned suggest you didn't use `mockFile` at all but some other class.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should create mockFile and you can write unit tests.

```
var mockFile= new MockFileData(new byte[4])//content as byte array
var mockFileSystem = new MockFileSystem();
```

Then you should add file directory into File System (`.AddDirectory(directory)`) and add file into file system (`.AddFile(directory,yourFileasbyteArray)`)

you need to focus on System.IO.Abstractions . It absolutely helps you.
As a result you need to create mock file and system.